# Unable to put calendar selected date into datetime C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I am experiencing troubles while creating a form for a greater project of mine. I need the selected date of a calendar to be saved into a datetime variable, however when i try to use:

```
DateTime valtdatum = calKalender.SelectedDate();
```

I am faced with syntax errors. I don't know if the SelectedDate-method is ASP.NET exclusive or if it is possible to use it with normal C#, however i do not know of any equivalent to this method.

Am i simply using the wrong method?
Is there a namespace that I need to enable?

Regards,
Jonathan

Answer (score 7):

> Am i simply using the wrong method? Is there a namespace that I need
>   to enable?

In ASP.Net [Calendar.SelectedDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.selecteddate.aspx) is a **property not a method**. You can use it like:

```
DateTime valtdatum = calKalender.SelectedDate;
```

You need to remove the `()` since its not a method.

**EDIT:**

Since in your comments you specified that its a `System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalender` then you need to do the following to get the Selected Date.

Set the property [`MaxSelectionCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.maxselectioncount.aspx) to `1`, so that only a single selection can be made, and then you can use [SelectionRange.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.selectionrange.start.aspx) property :

```
DateTime valtdatum = calKalender.SelectionRange.Start;
```

Or use [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.selectionstart.aspx) property directly.

```
DateTime valdatum = calKalender.SelectionStart;
```

Comment: I see. However it is still not working. I get the following error message: " 'System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedDate'.

The project is **not** an ASP.NET application, but a regular Windows Forms application.

Comment: @user1909530, check the edited part of the question, You may use tags in the question to properly tag the question with the language/technology

Comment: I found the problem, seems like `SelectedDate` is not C# syntax. I am now using `SelectionStart` and the program is doing what i want it to :).

Comment: @user1909530, glad it did, I have re-tagged your question with `winform`, and welcome to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime valtdatum = calKalender.SelectedDate;
```

Will work for you